# Using WhiteBox tools for Raster Calculation?

Tags: whitebox-tools

I understand the philosophy of [WhiteBox Tools](https://pypi.org/project/whitebox/) (one command for one process) but am wondering how best to use its math tools to create a slightly more complicated function.

E.g., (A/B + C/D)

I'm creating band ratios as given on the [Remote Sensing index database](https://www.indexdatabase.de/db/s-single.php?id=168) which sometimes require functions that are more complex than the functions of Mathematical and Statistical Analysis (e.g., divide two rasters and output a TIF, add two rasters and output a TIF, etc..).

I don't want to simply load by 10 or 15 bands into memory and work with them via numpy; WhiteBox is nice because it just loads the rasters required, when necessary.

Comment: Maybe try something like: `wbt.Divide(A, B, AB); wbt.Divide(C, D, CD); wbt.Add(AB, CD)`.  See the [math and stats](https://whitebox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#mathematical-and-statistical-analysis) tools and the [usage](https://whitebox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) docs.

Answer (score 1):

WhiteboxTools now has a [RasterCalculator](https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbt_book/available_tools/mathand_stats_tools.html#RasterCalculator) tool that means you no longer need to break complex mathematical operations into a series of simpler, single operations. Rasters are specified in the expression using quotations marks, and so, you get:

```
"A" / "B" + "C" / "D"
```